# Better Suited For Strings; substr() or split()

Tags: perl

Ok so this is kind of a follow on to the first question I asked which I think has been sufficiently answered. Anyways, on this part of my project I've got an array of strings. What is unique about these strings is that there is no apparent pattern. I've got a list of authors in a single string element of a large array. Some elements have two authors, some have more. Here's an example:

> Artem Chebotko and Shiyong Lu
>   Artem Chebotko, Shiyong Lu, Farshad Fotouhi, and Anthony Aristar
>   Craig Franke, Samuel Morin, Artem Chebotko, John Abraham, and Pearl Brazier
>   Liqiang Wang, Shiyong Lu, Xubo Fei, Artem Chebotko, H. Victoria Bryant, and Jeffrey L. Ram
>   Daniel Rebollar, Peter J. Vasquez Sr., and Artem Chebotko

So while its nice to have gotten rid of all of the HTML jazz that cluttered up my initial string, I'd like to 1) Put each author into its own string in an array, and 2) Make it so that I can sort the authors by last name. What I'd like to know is since there's no pattern to the array what would be better suited for this task, substr or split? Here's some notables about my array:

- Each line has an authors name, first and last and also sometimes a
  middle initial or Sr./Jr.
- If the line only has two authors they're seperated by a space and the
  word "and".(See above example)
- If the line has more than two each element is seperated by a comma
  and the last one is preceded by the word "and".
- In the event that the line has only one author no punctuation or the word "and" is needed.

I'd like to point out that I'm still quite new to Perl but I've come from C++ so I know a bit about computer logic. With that being said I think I know how both work but I just want to get the opinion of someone who is more familiar as to if either one will be better than the other. I know that computer code works on patterns which this doesn't really have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would use substr for this??

There appear to be three different possible separators to split on, so join them all in the regex for split with `|`:

```
@authors = split /, and |, | and /, $authors
```

In general, the problem of splitting last names isn't solvable, given multi word last names (e.g. von Neumann), and names where the "last name" comes first.  Heuristically, [Lingua::EN::NameParse](https://metacpan.org/module/Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aNameParse) will make an attempt.  (Similar modules are available for some other languages.)

Answer (score 1):

Just for some insight:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $re_and=qr/,? *and */;
my $re_com=qr/, */;
while(<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @authors = split /$re_and|$re_com/;
  for (@authors) {
    my ($n, $l, $m, $t);
    s/\s*$t\s*// if (($t) = /([JS]r\.)/);
    my @n = split;
    ($n, $m, $l) = @n if @n > 2;
    ($n, $l) = @n if @n == 2;
    print join ("::", grep {$_} ($n, $l, $m, $t)), "\n";
  }
}
__DATA__
Artem Chebotko and Shiyong Lu
Artem Chebotko, Shiyong Lu, Farshad Fotouhi, and Anthony Aristar
Craig Franke, Samuel Morin, Artem Chebotko, John Abraham, and Pearl Brazier
Liqiang Wang, Shiyong Lu, Xubo Fei, Artem Chebotko, H. Victoria Bryant, and Jeffrey L. Ram
Daniel Rebollar, Peter J. Vasquez Sr., and Artem Chebotko
```

**Output**

```
Artem::Chebotko
Shiyong::Lu
Artem::Chebotko
Shiyong::Lu
Farshad::Fotouhi
Anthony::Aristar
Craig::Franke
Samuel::Morin
Artem::Chebotko
John::Abraham
Pearl::Brazier
Liqiang::Wang
Shiyong::Lu
Xubo::Fei
Artem::Chebotko
H.::Bryant::Victoria
Jeffrey::Ram::L.
Daniel::Rebollar
Peter::Vasquez::J.::Sr.
Artem::Chebotko
```